# How to add user-defined function too parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query gives me some error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

```
select 
Count(Page) as VisitingCount,
dbo.fn_GetActivityLogsArranger(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)as [Time] 
 from scr_SecuristLog     
where Date between '2009-04-30' and '2009-05-02'    
and [user] in(select USERNAME               
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities 
where customerID=Convert(varchar,4) and ID=Convert(varchar,43) )    
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) asc 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetActivityLogsArranger]
(
@time AS nvarchar(max)
)

RETURNS  nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
declare @Return varchar(30)

select @Return = case 
when @time between '15:00' and '15:30' then '15:00-15:30'
when @time between '15:30' and '16:00' then '15:30-16:00'
when @time between '16:00' and '16:30' then '16:00-16:30'
when @time between '16:00' and '16:30' then '16:00-16:30' 
when @time between '16:30' and '17:00' then '16:30-17:00' 
when @time between '17:00' and '17:30' then '17:00-17:30' 
when @time between '17:30' and '18:00' then '17:30-18:00'
else 'Unknown'
end
 Return @Return
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a parentheses

```
select 
Count(Page) as VisitingCount,
dbo.fn_GetActivityLogsArranger(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)**)** as [Time] 
 from scr_SecuristLog     
where Date between '2009-04-30' and '2009-05-02'    
and [user] in(select USERNAME               
    from scr_CustomerAuthorities 
where customerID=Convert(varchar,4) and ID=Convert(varchar,43) )    
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) asc
```

Comment: Thank alot. you are correct. Look please another ques.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829089/how-to-call-user-defined-function-in-order-to-use-with-select-group-by-order-by