# T-SQL - What is an inline-view?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I recently answered this question [how-to-call-user-defined-function-in-order-to-use-with-select-group-by-order-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829089/how-to-call-user-defined-function-in-order-to-use-with-select-group-by-order-by/829106#829106)

My answer was to use an inline view to perform the function and then group on that.

In comments the asker has not understood my response and has asked for some sites / references to help explain it.

I've done a quick google and haven't found any great resources that explain in detail what an inline view is and where they are useful.

Does anyone have anything that can help to explain what an inline view is?

Comment: I'm not really sure what is meant by "inline view" either but what you linked to is really a subquery.

Comment: A "subquery" in the FROM clause is an inline view and is executed as if it was a View.

Comment: By definition you do not have a subquery in the from clause, it is  a derived table in SQL Server.

Comment: @HLGEM: So, what is the actual difference between a "derived table" and a "subquery"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure "inline view" is a term coined by Oracle.  I use the term myself but it seems specific to that community.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view):
An inline view is a SELECT statement in the FROM-clause of another SELECT statement. In-line views are commonly used simplify complex queries by removing join operations and condensing several separate queries into a single query.

Comment: for the examples in the given link, I call those "derived tables", do a google on than and you will find similar examples and articles

Comment: @KM - I wouldn't doubt it, people feel comfortable with different names for concepts depending on their background.

Comment: search sql server help for "derived tables", they are mentioned in the first line of the documentation for the "FROM (Transact-SQL)" entry.  I didn't see anything on "inline views".

Answer (score 4):

I think another term (possibly a SQL Server term) is 'derived table'

For instance, this article:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1042

or

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-derived-tables-to-calculate-aggregate-values

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, an "inline view" is just another expression for a row-returning sub-query.

In other words — an SQL expression that could be replaced entirely by the name of a view (therefore, a correlated sub-query does not qualify as an inline view).

Comment: That being said, I am no fan of the cargo cult that is behind using the "correct" terminology. Personally I never used "inline view" or "derived table" or whatnot. It's a sub-query -- there is no need for this fine-grained distinction. (Well, maybe it's just me.)

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163346.aspx) claims that an inline view is another term for a derived table, and refers to the same thing everyone else is describing in this thread (subquery in FROM).
An alternative in sql server 2005 and up is the common table expression.

Answer (score 1):

- Inline view are introduce Oracle 7.2 .
- Inline view are special type of query used in Oracle Database.
- Inline view we are using in sub query in place of table name with in parent query.

They can be used as

```
Select * from (sub query) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another term often more commonly used for an inline view is 'Embedded Select Statement'

So a select inside a select.

Answer (score 0):

An inline view is a **virtual table** created in the from statement during the execution of the code/program