# Are table variables and virtual tables the same thing?

Tags: sql-server, virtual-table

Are virtual tables and table variables the same in SQL Server?  What is a virtual table?  Why we need virtual tables, and how do you create one?

Comment: It depends on what you understand by *virtual table*. Could you perhaps give an example? Because it might just happen that you misunderstood the meaning of the term itself. A [*view*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190174 "Views (SQL Server)") could be called a virtual table. An "[inline view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829354/t-sql-what-is-an-inline-view "T-SQL - What is an inline-view?")" (or "inline table") could also be called a virtual table.

Comment: @AndriyM - Also I've seen the term "virtual table" used to refer to a purely logical construct in [Logical Query Processing](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`No`, They aren't same.

Go through this answer for clear understanding.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: sorry, for that i am not able to give an example because this question asked to me in interview.The question asked in interview is that what the different between temp and virtual table. When i searched on internet for virtual table. I did not find the  answer. So Please clear me first what is virtaul table with example

Comment: Please someboay can give me idea what is virtual table in sql sever with example.